# DAX - RANKX with 2 Measures

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a matrix that shows me for each article 2 values:
[image]

I have a measure "Value 1" that shows me a number and I have a second measure.
Now I would like to get the ranking first based on Value 2 and then on Value 1.
For that purpose I have created a new measure "Ranking Value" with this logic:

```
Value 1 + (Value 2 / 100)
```

This way I get the right value for RANKX.

Now using this RANKX function:

```
RANKX (ALLSELECTED(Item[Article]), [Measure 2])
```

is not working
I always get the rank 1 for each article.

But why?

Comment: It might be useful to know the definitions of the two measures Value 1 and Value 2.

Comment: There are just simple SUM functions.